# Using LISTAGG with single byte "char" type in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Using:

```
LISTAGG (DISTINCT con.contype, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY con.contype)
```

gives error:

`Function "text("char")" not supported`

It looks like Redshift doesn't support `"char"` types, is there any approach to make this work?

Comment: Redshift supports char datatype.  What is con.contype?  What kind of table is it in? (user, system, external ...)

Comment: It doesn't support the [single byte "char" type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html). `pg_constraints` holds `contype`

Comment: I suspect you may be dealing with an incorrect error message.  You see listagg() is a compute node only function and I suspect pg_constraint is a leader node only table.  One way to confirm is to select pg_constraint into a user table and see if it works (just doing one column would be sufficient to know but you may need to cast some data types).  If this fails you will need to fall back to a different approach to get the data into the compute nodes to run listagg().

Comment: My knowledge of sql is pretty limited right now but this is what I ran originally:
`SELECT
 LISTAGG(DISTINCT CAST(con.contype AS VARCHAR), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CAST(con.contype AS VARCHAR))
FROM
 pg_constraint con,
 stv_tbl_perm;`
I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly but I added a system table so listagg wouldn't complain. This results in the same error above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the code you are running helps a ton.  Reproduction was exact but what is interesting is how the error changes with slight modifications.  This is what I expected and is due to the networked cluster architecture of Redshift.  You see system work is done on the leader node while the bulk of query execution is done on compute nodes.  When you fire up a 2 node Redshift cluster you actually get 3 computers - 2 running as compute nodes and 1 leaders node (all of the same HW size and type).  This structure works well when you are working with user data but queries that source from system tables can become an issue as this data only lives on the leader node.  Redshift is not set up to move source data from the leader to computer nodes (in many cases).

If we run your query we get the full error output of:

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command: SELECT
> LISTAGG(DISTINCT CAST(con.contype AS VARCHAR),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER
> BY CAST(con.contype AS VARCHAR)) FROM pg_constraint con,
> stv_tbl_pe...
>
> Amazon Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one
> per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;
>
> Warnings: Function "text("char")" not supported. Function
> "text("char")" not supported. Function "text("char")" not supported.

The key bit is "Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one
per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;" which isn't the clearest message for sure but is generated when the source data needs to move from leader to compute.  The "Function "text("char")" not supported." is just a warning and not central to what is going on.

The simplest example of when this happens can be seen simply by first running

```
SELECT con.contype
FROM pg_constraint con, stv_tbl_perm;
```

which produces the expected output.  Leader node is the source and the data is just sent out to the client which is connected to the leader node.  No problems.

However if we add a cast to the SQL (along with the join), Redshift decides that the compute nodes need to get involved and thing error out:

```
SELECT CAST(con.contype AS VARCHAR)
FROM pg_constraint con,
     stv_tbl_perm;
```

Produces "Amazon Invalid operation: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.;".  In other words the data can't get to the compute nodes.

This is a common enough issue that (I've answered 3 of these in the past 2 weeks) and there are solutions.  You need to define a path from the leader node back to the compute nodes.  One straight forward way is to just read the data out and insert it back in but folks don't like the complexity of this.  Another way is to define a stored procedure that  does basically the same thing.  Looks like:

1. Select the needed data from the leader node into a cursor
2. Copy this data to a temp table which will be on the compute nodes
3. Run your complex query on the temp data

Below is the stored code for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure pg_const()
AS
$$
DECLARE 
  row record;
BEGIN
  drop table if exists temp_pg_const;
  create temp table temp_pg_const (contype varchar(16));
  for row in SELECT con.contype
            FROM pg_constraint con, stv_tbl_perm
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO temp_pg_const(contype) SELECT DECODE(row.contype, 'c', 'c', 'f', 'f', 'p', 'p', 'u', 'u', '?') ;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

call pg_const();

SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT CAST(con.contype AS VARCHAR),',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CAST(con.contype AS VARCHAR))
FROM temp_pg_const con;
```

The stored procedure definition only needs to be run when the code changes.  Just the call of the procedure is needed to update the temp table.  The added complexity in this case is the datatype incompatibility you mentioned which is why I used a DECODE().  Again I couldn't join and cast on the leader node but I could DECODE().

There are lots of ways to split this up between what is run on the leader and moved through a cursor to a temp table and what is done post-temp-table.  You could just copy the system tables directly to temp tables using this method and do all the work on the compute side if you like.

One thing to pay attention to is that this process isn't fast and should not be run on large amounts of data.  The stored procedure is looping on the rows of the cursor which will take a long time if you have millions of rows.  If it is a large amount of data moving it out of Redshift and back in is likely the fastest route.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
LISTAGG(DISTINCT con.contype::text, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY con.contype::text)
```

Comment: I tried doing this earlier, but the same error shows up

Comment: @vrare . . . Hmmm, this is strange.  It definitely should accept `text`.

Comment: That's what I originally thought but trying to use `CAST` or `CONVERT` results in this message: `Function "bpchar("char")" not supported.` This whole thing seems tricky and I'm wondering if casting will even work